# Issue import Data From Excel to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, excel-2003

Hi I m importing Data from Excel to SQL Server 2005. It is Working fine. The problem is

1) In one full column of Excel i have some Raw information how to spilt those information and store in SQL fields.

2) There is Single quotes (') in many fields so how to convert those to as something like ('') before taking to SQL.

Comment: Do you need to fix this data just once, or will you be importing a spreadsheet in this format repeatedly?

Comment: The Spreadsheet needed to be imported periodically

Answer (score 0):

First export your Excel data to tab-delimited or CSV.  Then make your changes using Perl or sed or an editor with a regex find and replace.

Comment: Jeremy, can you give me some more details on it.